# Copy data from one matrix to another in C

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, copy

I have two matrix dynamically allocated.I want to copy all the data from the first matrix and center it by a border to the second one.Here is my code which apparently does not work properly so I would be grateful for some help:

The first matrix:

```
    unsigned char ** sudo=(unsigned char **) malloc (width*sizeof (unsigned char*));

if ( sudo != NULL){
    for (k=0; k<width ;k++){
        sudo[k] =(unsigned char*) calloc (height,sizeof (unsigned char));
    }
}
```

The second one:

```
unsigned char ** fmatr=(unsigned char **) malloc ((width+border)*sizeof (unsigned char*));

if ( fmatr != NULL){
    for (k=0; k<(width+border) ;k++){
        fmatr[k] =(unsigned char*) calloc ((height+border),sizeof (unsigned char));
    }
}
```

How I center first matrix in the middle of the second one:

```
    for(i=0,k=0;i<(width+border);i++,k++){
      for(j=0,l=0;j<(height+border);j++,l++){
        if((i>(2*border)) && (j>(2*border))){
            fmatr[i][j]=sudo[k][l];
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to centralize the data, why do you use (i > 2* border) and not (i >= border) and (i < height + border)?

Comment: Standard warning: do not cast the result of `malloc` in C! C is not C++. And note that this is no matrix, which would be a 2D array. You have an array of pointers to (arrays of) `unsigned char`. Copying a matrx would be simply a single `memcpy(dest, src, width * height)`. As you use `char` elements, the size of each element is guaranteed `1` by the standard (you can exploit this in your code, too).

Comment: Please don't remove the code or relevant information from your question.  This site serves as an archive of programming knowledge, and clearing the contents of a question removes information that someone else might need.

Answer (score 0):

Since the first matrix has width x height entries, you want to loop from 0 to width-1 (not width-1+border) and from 0 to height-1 (not height-1+border).  Similarly, you want to add `border/2` to the index of the second array when assigning.

```
for(i=0;i<width;i++){
  for(j=0;j<height;j++){
    fmatr[i+(border/2)][j+(border/2)]=sudo[i][j];
  }
}
```

Comment: @b-parker I see you posted a follow up question that seems to suggest this answer addressed your question.  If that's the case, feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).